# install Frama-C on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, frama-c

How do I install a current Frama-C release and its prerequisites on Macs?

I have a laptop running Mac OS X 10.6.8 and a desktop running Mac OS X 10.7.5
which I can install software on.  I also have access to a lab of machines
running Mac OS X 10.8 which our technical support people will install stuff on
if I ask nicely.

I have a student who is interested in program analysis and needs something
that we have a fighting chance of understanding and adding to.  I was already
aware of Frama-C, and a colleague at another university recommended it.

I had previously tried to install Frama-C and failed miserably.  The colleague
commented that he'd had the same experience.  Well, times change.  So I visited
the Frama-C web site, was more impressed and keener to have it than ever, and
set about it.

The frama-c.com download page doesn't have links to any binaries for the
current (Flourine 3) release for any platform.  The link to installation
instruction takes me to a page that says to download the auto-installer.
What auto-installer?

There are instructions for an old version of Mac OS X, but following them
didn't work; loading one set of prerequisites as instructed produced a
state where the next prerequisite (gtksourceview) would not install.

Of course I checked the older releases, and I see that there's a Nitrogen
version for Mac OS X Leopard, but "Please untar the archive as root in /"
asks me to perform the impossible.  I don't have a root account and will
never be given one (the machines all belong to the university).  It is
perfectly possible to install gcc and clang anywhere you like; why does
Frama-C want to be in /?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Pascal's answer, you can also have a look to [opam](http://opam.ocamlpro.com/), which is a source package manager for OCaml applications. It appears to run on MacOS X, and there are packages for Frama-C's Oxygen and Fluorine.

Answer (score 4):

All Frama-C binary packages want to install in / (precisely, in /usr/local/Frama-C) because Frama-C uses GTK+ and various GTK+-related libraries that were never designed to run from anything other than a fixed location. They load configuration files and resources from paths that have been hard-coded at compile-time. GCC and Clang install anywhere because they don't rely on GTK+. Like them, the command-line version of Frama-C can be relocated through various environment variables listed [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/frama-c.1.html).

Note that to take advantage of a binary package, you would only need one symbolic link pointing from /usr/local/Frama-C to the place where you really extracted the files, if your administrator(s) can grant you that. Binary packages only work for one OS X version. For packages available from the official website, this version is usually 10.6 (Snow Leopard).

---

I have ceased making Frama-C binary packages for two reasons:

1. by removing features and support for hardware configurations in each of the last two OS X releases, Apple has fragmented the OS X landscape in a way I don't have the time to deal with. You mention 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8 in your question. I also have Macs running each of 10.6, 10.7 and 10.8. They are all incompatible (when trying to build a software package that includes a compiler).
2. I have much less time available now that I am participating in the creation of a start-up that offers Frama-C-based static analysis to interested industrial users.

This said, Frama-C the Open-Source advanced research prototype continues to be developed and maintained, and continues to be a great testbed to experiment in. You can install Frama-C without root access on a Mac in two ways apart from what you have already tried:

1. Install only the command-line version. Then the only dependency is a recent version of the OCaml compiler. Frama-C's configure will detect that you do not have the GTK libraries and will not try to use them. Installation should take 20 minutes at most for a recent OCaml + the latest Frama-C.
2. Install a recent Linux distribution in a virtual machine. Use that distribution's package manager to obtain all the GTK+ dependencies. If the distribution's OCaml package is recent enough, use that and then the lablgtk-2 package, otherwise, compile OCaml and then lablgtk-2 from source. Then compile Frama-C.

For Fluorine, the oldest supported OCaml version is 3.12.1.

Comment: never mind the Carbon version works like a charm for Mavericks ! :)

Answer (score 1):

with macports:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig
sudo port install opam
opam init
  Y
eval `opam config env`
sudo port install gtksourceview2 lablgtk2 ocaml-ocamlgraph
opam install frama-c
```

Comment: you must install "ocaml" before doing "opam init" !

Comment: Damii: yes, but `sudo port install opam` installs already ocaml as dependency

Comment: I did tried what you did, and i cannot install it yet :( at least on mavericks